# Using a range with GETDATE & BETWEEN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm fairly new to T-SQL and am still learning so please bear with me on this one...I've tried several ways to do this with no luck. I have my 'current' and 90+ days but it's the 30 and 60 days that I'm struggling with. Why can't I use the 'between' clause?

```
   ,[CURRENT]=(SELECT sum (cle.[Amount]) 
     FROM [NISNAV].[dbo].[NIS$Cust_ Ledger Entry] cl3 left outer join 
     [NISNAV].[dbo].[NIS$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry] cle on cl3.[entry no_]=cle.[cust_ ledger entry no_]
     where C.[NO_]=CL3.[CUSTOMER NO_] AND cl3.[open]='1' AND cl3.[Due Date]>getdate()-30) 



   ,[30 DAYS]=(SELECT sum (cle.[Amount])
     FROM [NISNAV].[dbo].[NIS$Cust_ Ledger Entry] cl3 left outer join 
     [NISNAV].[dbo].[NIS$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry] cle on cl3.[entry no_]=cle.[cust_ ledger entry no_]
     where C.[NO_]=CL3.[CUSTOMER NO_] AND cl3.[open]='1' AND cl3.[Due Date]BETWEEN GETDATE()-31 AND getdate()-59) 

   ,[60 DAYS]=(SELECT sum (cle.[Amount]) 
     FROM [NISNAV].[dbo].[NIS$Cust_ Ledger Entry] cl3 left outer join 
     [NISNAV].[dbo].[NIS$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry] cle on cl3.[entry no_]=cle.[cust_ ledger entry no_]
     where C.[NO_]=CL3.[CUSTOMER NO_] AND cl3.[open]='1' AND cl3.[Due Date] BETWEEN GETDATE()-60 AND getdate()-89) 

      ,[90 + DAYS]=((SELECT sum (cle.[Amount]) 
     FROM [NISNAV].[dbo].[NIS$Cust_ Ledger Entry] cl3 left outer join 
     [NISNAV].[dbo].[NIS$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry] cle on cl3.[entry no_]=cle.[cust_ ledger entry no_]
     where C.[NO_]=CL3.[CUSTOMER NO_] AND cl3.[open]='1' AND cl3.[Due Date]<=getdate()-90 ))
```

I know there are entries for that particular customer in both of those buckets.

suggestions?

Comment: Two bits of opinion: Get into the habit of using `DATEADD` instead of arithmetic on `DATE` and `DATETIME` values. (And `DATEDIFF` and the rest of the date/time functions.) Clearer, more flexible, ... . When writing code that uses `GETDATE()` repeatedly, consider saving a value and using it throughout, i.e. `declare @Now as DateTime = GetDate();`. Although it is treated as a constant within a single query, i.e. all of your calls will return the same value, when you have multiple statements the value may change causing rare, but considerable, confusion.

Comment: It's a bad practice to use `BETWEEN` with `datetime` types. Get in the habit of using `date >= date_from AND date < date_to`. It's easier than fixing your code later.

Comment: Specifically, if you ran your query right now, you would lose the records where `[Due Date] = '2015-02-22'` because `'2015-02-22' < GETDATE()-59'` and `'2015-02-22'` > `GETDATE()-60`.  You aren't capturing those entries in either [30 Days] or [60 Days]

Comment: I want to add to what @anon said. If using date time and you need to include all events from `date_to` it need to be set one day after. It is because, if you want to capture all events up to 20150422 included, 20150422T22:00:00 is greater than 20150422

Comment: @anon that makes sense...but I'm a little confused on how to use the date_to and date_from ... do you happen to have a link you can suggest that I can read on how to use it properly. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When filtering a range of dates, BETWEEN expects the earlier date to come before the later date.

You need to reverse the sides of the BETWEEN so that the older date (with highest -value) comes first:

```
   ,[30 DAYS]=(SELECT sum (cle.[Amount])
     FROM [NISNAV].[dbo].[NIS$Cust_ Ledger Entry] cl3 left outer join 
     [NISNAV].[dbo].[NIS$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry] cle on cl3.[entry no_]=cle.[cust_ ledger entry no_]
     where C.[NO_]=CL3.[CUSTOMER NO_] AND cl3.[open]='1' AND cl3.[Due Date]BETWEEN GETDATE()-59 AND getdate()-31) 

   ,[60 DAYS]=(SELECT sum (cle.[Amount]) 
     FROM [NISNAV].[dbo].[NIS$Cust_ Ledger Entry] cl3 left outer join 
     [NISNAV].[dbo].[NIS$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry] cle on cl3.[entry no_]=cle.[cust_ ledger entry no_]
     where C.[NO_]=CL3.[CUSTOMER NO_] AND cl3.[open]='1' AND cl3.[Due Date] BETWEEN GETDATE()-89 AND getdate()-60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of four separate subqueries, you can use one query with `CASE` statements

```
SELECT
  [CURRENT] = SUM(CASE WHEN cl3.[Due Date] >= DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE())
                       THEN cle.[Amount]
                  END)
 ,[30 DAYS] = SUM(CASE WHEN cl3.[Due Date] <  DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE())
                        AND cl3.[Due Date] >= DATEADD(day,-60,GETDATE())
                       THEN cle.[Amount]
                  END)
 ,[60 DAYS] = SUM(CASE WHEN cl3.[Due Date] <  DATEADD(day,-60,GETDATE())
                        AND cl3.[Due Date] >= DATEADD(day,-90,GETDATE())
                       THEN cle.[Amount]
                  END)
 ,[90 DAYS] = SUM(CASE WHEN cl3.[Due Date] <  DATEADD(day,-90,GETDATE())
                       THEN cle.[Amount]
                  END)
FROM [NISNAV].[dbo].[NIS$Cust_ Ledger Entry] cl3
LEFT OUTER JOIN [NISNAV].[dbo].[NIS$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry] cle
  ON( cl3.[entry no_]=cle.[cust_ ledger entry no_])
WHERE C.[NO_]=CL3.[CUSTOMER NO_]
  AND cl3.[open]='1'
```